How to unencrypt Grsync restored backups?
I just restored my Backups from Rsync, but everything is encrypted and I have to input password to access them every single time.
I've tried changing the permissions on the folder but no luck on removing the encryption.
I added the encryption when backing it up thinking, it will just require me to input password once during restoration.
My question now is how to fix this, get rid of the encryption and so on. The stuff was encrypted with Grsync.

